# Eclipse: How to open an editor programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, editor

I'm wondering how I can open an editor programmatically. I first created the appropriated file and then I want to open the editor for this type of file. But I'm not able to open the editor then.

```
...
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
PlcEditor editor = new PlcEditor(emfResource);
page.openEditor(editor, "test");
...
```

I already had the following solution (which works), but here I wasn't able to call the constructr of my editor:

```
....
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
IEditorPart openEditor = IDE.openEditor(page, plcFile);
....
```

Answer (score 2):

First you must define your editor to Eclipse using the `org.eclipse.ui.editors` extension point:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
  <editor
        name="Sample Multi-page Editor"
        extensions="mpe"
        icon="icons/sample.gif"
        contributorClass="tested.editors.MultiPageEditorContributor"
        class="tested.editors.MultiPageEditor"
        id="tested.editors.MultiPageEditor">
  </editor>
</extension>
```

(above is as created by the provided multi-page editor example).

You can then use:

```
IDE.openEditor(page, file, "tested.editors.MultiPageEditor");
```

to open the editor on an `IFile` specifying your editor id, or for the `extension` specified the editor will be the default and you can just use

```
IDE.openEditor(page, file);
```

You can also use the `contentTypeBinding` child element of `editor` to specify content types then editor will handle.

Comment: Hi greg, that's what I've already done. I just wanted to know how I can use IDE.openEditor(..) and provide arguments to the constructor of my editor. Using the above one, the constructor with no arguments is used: public PlcEditor() {...}

Comment: No, you can't specify arguments to the constructor.

Comment: And what about creating the editor by myself (like I did in my question) and then open it somehow? Is this possible? Can't doubt that there is no way to do this.

Comment: Sorry, no, just checked and `org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage` which implements `IWorkbenchPage` has no support for previously constructed editors. You could use a pure Eclipse e4 RCP application where you can create editors any way you like, but that is a very big change.

Comment: Ok, thx anyway..that's pretty bad at all, as it's hard for me now to build up a tree in the multipageeditor

Comment: You could use your own implementation of `IEditorInput` to contain all the information you need as input to the editor.

Comment: I tried this, but every time I reopen the file, a new instance of the editor is created and my assigned resource from the first call is removed

Comment: Hi Greg, I want to open the files in the Editor as Read only mode,Is there a way to do that. can you please let me know on this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: @raj Please don't ask new questions as comments. Eclipse has no concept of read only editors, it would depend on the specific editor what you can do for this.