# Open java source in Eclipse based on project path

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to open a java source in Eclipse where the code is already in an Eclipse Project.

I tried to achieve this with [Eclipse: How to open an editor programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817742/eclipse-how-to-open-an-editor-programatically), but therefore you need an IPath and this IPath is only available when you build a plugIn. So I was wondering on how to implement this without a plugIn. Basically, I wanna have a class with a method which will open the java source in Eclipse based on a parameter that value is the project path, i.e. "com.MyProject.HelloWorld".

Comment: It is not just the IPath, everything in that answer has to run in a plugin. To work with Eclipse editors and the workspace you have to write a plugin.

Comment: Okay, I see. I tried already to implement a plugIn, but what I have problems with and why I not wanna use a plugIn, is that I don't know on how to call the plugin programmatically with a parameter. Basically, as already mentioned, by calling a method with the class path, i.e. MyClass.OpenSourceInEditor("com.MyProject.HelloWorld")

Comment: I found already Platform.getBundle("plugin id").start() but this solution is not working for me.

Comment: If you mean from some program outside of Eclipse you can't. To work with Eclipse code you have to write everything in Eclipse plugins. Your plugins would add menu items and the like to Eclipse.

Comment: So you mean it is not possible to have several buttons on a GUI which would open a Java source in Eclipse, even when I know the class path? I have the code on how to open a java source in Eclipse, but what I wanna achieve is to parameterize what source Eclipse should open.

Comment: You can start up a new Eclipse and open a specific file using the command line [see here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/OpenFileFeature). That is all you can do from outside of Eclipse.